# Multiply two pandas dataframes based on their indices and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have two dataframes with the following structure:

```
id           0          1         2           
time      0    1     0    1   0     1            
id time                                            id    0      1     2                 
0  0      a1   a2    b1   b2   c1   c2             id 
   1      a3   a4    b3   b4   c3   c4             0     w00   w01   w02 
1  0      d1   d2    d1   d2   e1   e2     and     1     w10   w11   w12  
   1      d3   d4    d3   d4   e3   e4             2     w20   w21   w22  
2  0      f1   f2    g1   g2   h1   h2            
   1      f3   f4    g3   g4   h3   h4
```

I need to obtain a sequence of matrices such that every element of the first DataFrame indexed by their id's must be multiplied by the corresponding element of the second DataFrame indexed by the same id's, i.e.:

```
id               0           |    id                1           |    id              2  
time         0       1       |    time          0       1       |    time        0       1 
id time                      |    id time                       |    id time
0  0      a1*w00   a2*w00    |    0  0       b1*w01   b2*w01    |    0  0     c1*w02   c2*w02
   1      a3*w00   a4*w00    |       1       b3*w01   b4*w01    |       1     c3*w02   c4*w02
```

and so on. My current current implementation looks as follows, but it is taking a long time with a sample size of just 200 and 3 time periods (and I need to repeat this hundreds of times), so I was wondering if there is a way to vectorize/optimize this. I don't know if this matters, but the end goal is to add up all the elements of each matrix obtained.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 3
T = 2
NT = N*T

# JUST GENERATING FAKE DATA
ind = []
for i in range(N):
    for t in range(T):
        i_t = (i,t)
        ind.append(i_t)
        
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ind)

eps1 = np.random.randint(1,10,(NT,1))
eps2 = np.random.randint(1,10,(NT,1))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(eps1.dot(eps2.transpose()), index=index2, columns=index2)

w = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(N,1))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(w.dot(w.transpose()))

E = pd.DataFrame(index=range(N), columns=range(N))

# THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO VECTORIZE/OPTIMIZE
for i in range(N):
     for j in range(N):
        E.loc[i][j] = (df1.loc[i][j] * df2.loc[i][j]).to_numpy().sum()
        
E
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
(df1.mul(df2, level=0)       # multiply two df, align by level 0
    .sum(level=0)            # sum along columns, align by level 0
    .sum(axis=1, level=0)    # sum along rows, aling by level 0
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I can increase the sample size by a lot!

Comment: by any chance do you know a way to further speed this computation even further?